# Is there any parameters to be set so that the forecast and value get closer using the ARIMA fct predict()?

Tags: python, time-series, arima, forecast

After checking for the stationarity of my Time Series Dataset, I got the `ARIMA(p,d,q)` params and I could fit my model. Now while plotting the Actual vs Fitted, I noticed a "big" gap between both.

Is it normal or is there any parameters to be set so that the forecast and value getting closer using the function `predict()` before moving forward with train and test phases?

[image: closer]
[image: not that closed]